# Adding data after submitting form in Django admin

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin

(I'm newish to Django and using a codebase with Django 1.8)

There's a model (Survey) which has a many to many relationship with another (Page) and a reference to a starting page (Page). Creating this in the admin panel would be really messy for the user, but it can be worked out if they make a few Yes/No decisions.

So, in the admin add page I have added some select fields that are not part of the model (More or less 'Include Section A?' / 'Include Section B?' / 'Include Section C?'...etc), and based on what the user chooses here I want to add different keys to the page_links on Survey and the starting_page.

Working these out is fine, but when the form / model is saved the page_links and start_page aren't there, presumably because they're not part of the form.

I've tried adding them to cleaned_data (in save or clean) but that doesn't work.

Here's the model:

```py
class Survey(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    start_page = models.ForeignKey('Page', related_name='surveys_started', null=True)
    page_links = models.ManyToManyField('PageLink', related_name='surveys')
```

and here's the Admin:

```py
class SurveyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'fields': ('title', ),
        }),
        ('User Decisions', {
            'fields': ('do_a', 'do_b', 'do_c', )
        }),
    )

    form = SurveyForm
```

and the Form:

```py
class SurveyForm(forms.ModelForm):

    title = forms.CharField(required=True)
    do_a = forms.ChoiceField(label='Do A',choices=[(True, 'Yes'), (False, 'No')], initial=True)
    do_b = forms.ChoiceField(label='Do B',choices=[(True, 'Yes'), (False, 'No')], initial=True)
    do_c = forms.ChoiceField(label='Do C',choices=[(True, 'Yes'), (False, 'No')], initial=True)

    def save(self, commit=True):
        title = self.cleaned_data.get('title', 'N/A')
        do_a = self.cleaned_data.get('do_a', True)
        do_b = self.cleaned_data.get('do_b', True)
        do_c = self.cleaned_data.get('do_c', True)

        # Assume these two work fine
        page_links = work_out_links(do_a, do_b, do_c)
        start_page = get_start_page(do_a, do_b, do_c)

        self.cleaned_data['page_links'] = page_links
        self.cleaned_data['start_page'] = start_page
        return super(SurveyForm, self).save(commit=commit)

    class Meta:
        exclude = ['start_page']
```

Basically I just want the contents of 'page_links' and 'start_page' in save_model to be in the Survey instance in the DB.

(Note: I know it seems from this that I should create an intermediate 'Section' and just get the user to choose those, but assume there's reasons I'm not doing that if possible 8) )

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Does `ModelForm` have a method called `save_model` in 1.8? Isn't it just `save`?

Comment: @CoffeeBasedLifeform Yup that was a typo, just edited it out, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so it turned out an approach that worked was to return the form data normally, and then do the assignment in the admin.ModelAdmin's save_model method.

So the form became:

```
class SurveyForm(forms.ModelForm):

    title = forms.CharField(required=True)
    do_a = forms.ChoiceField(label='Do A',choices=[(True, 'Yes'), (False, 'No')], initial=True)
    do_b = forms.ChoiceField(label='Do B',choices=[(True, 'Yes'), (False, 'No')], initial=True)
    do_c = forms.ChoiceField(label='Do C',choices=[(True, 'Yes'), (False, 'No')], initial=True)

    def save(self, commit=True):
        title = self.cleaned_data.get('title', 'N/A')
        do_a = self.cleaned_data.get('do_a', True)
        do_b = self.cleaned_data.get('do_b', True)
        do_c = self.cleaned_data.get('do_c', True)

        # Assume these two work fine
        page_links = work_out_links(do_a, do_b, do_c)
        start_page = get_start_page(do_a, do_b, do_c)

        self.cleaned_data['page_links'] = page_links
        self.cleaned_data['start_page'] = start_page
        return super(SurveyForm, self).save(commit=commit)

    class Meta:
        exclude = ['start_page']
```

and the ModelAdmin became:

```py
class SurveyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'fields': ('title', ),
        }),
        ('User Decisions', {
            'fields': ('do_a', 'do_b', 'do_c', )
        }),
    )

    form = SurveyForm

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.start_page = form.cleaned_data['start_page']
        obj.save()
        # Need to save _before_ adding foreign keys
        obj.page_links = form.cleaned_data['page_links']
```

This works nicely, (Edit) though I should almost certainly move more logic from the form.save to the modelAdmin.save_model.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the instance, that `ModelForm.save()` is saving, is constructed earlier in the cleaning process in `ModelForm._post_clean`:

```
def _post_clean(self):
    ...
    try:
        self.instance = construct_instance(self, self.instance, opts.fields, opts.exclude)
    except ValidationError as e:
        self._update_errors(e)

    try:
        self.instance.full_clean(exclude=exclude, validate_unique=False)
    except ValidationError as e:
        self._update_errors(e)
    ...

def save(self, commit=True):
    ...
    if commit:
        # If committing, save the instance and the m2m data immediately.
        self.instance.save()
        self._save_m2m()
    else:
        # If not committing, add a method to the form to allow deferred
        # saving of m2m data.
        self.save_m2m = self._save_m2m
    return self.instance
```

Thus, `ModelForm.save()` is not actually using the `cleaned_data` at all, which means altering the contents of `cleaned_data` in that method has no effect.

The answer you provided yourself works, because you use the `ModelForm.save()` method to add data to `form.cleaned_data` that you then later use in `ModelAdmin.save_model`.
 Technically, this is fine as, from the ModelForm's perspective, changing `cleaned_data` has no impact on how the instance is saved/constructed.

A cleaner approach would be to add a `clean` method to the ModelForm that adds the data you need. `clean()` happens before `_post_clean()` so any changes you make to `cleaned_data` would be included when constructing the instance (and when *saving* the instance).

```
def clean(self):
    self.cleaned_data['page_links'] = work_out_links(do_a, do_b, do_c)
    self.cleaned_data['start_page'] = get_start_page(do_a, do_b, do_c)
    return self.cleaned_data
```